# Is there a POSIX way of setting zeroth argument of a target application?

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix, exec

In `bash` you can use `exec -a` and in `zsh` you can alternatively also set `ARGV0` to execute a program with a certain zeroth argument but is there also a POSIX way of doing so?

As suggested [in this one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111455/#comment23009844_16111579) you could create a (temporary) symbolic link to achieve this but this way I couldn't set the new zeroth argument value to truly any arbitrary value, e.g. the command with a certain absolute path. So is there any other solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there's no POSIX way, other than compiling a C program that does it. As a quick and dirty one:

```
$ echo 'int main(int c,char*v[]){
  execvp(v[1],&v[2]);perror(v[1]);return 127;}'>r.c && make r
$ ./r ps zzz -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  7412  7411  0 10:44 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas 21187  7412  0 22:33 pts/4    00:00:00 zzz -f
```

`exec -a` is supported by `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, `busybox ash` (since version 1.27.0), `yash`, `mksh` ([since version r50e](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm#r50e)), the [Schily Bourne Shell](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html) (since August 2015) so is the most widespread among shells.

Probably the most portable would be to resort to `perl` which is more likely to be available than a C compiler.

```
$ perl -e 'exec {shift} @ARGV' ps zzz -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  7554  7411  0 10:58 pts/12   00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas  7630  7554  0 11:02 pts/12   00:00:00 zzz -f
```

Answer (score 15):

For completeness, here are some C and C++ programs for doing this that people have *already* compiled.

Going by the commentary that you point to, your apparent motivation for asking for "a POSIX way" of doing this is to know how one can achieve this same end with shells such as the Debian Almquist shell, the MirBSD Korn shell (before version R50e), the Debian POSIX-Compliant Ordinary shell, and other shells that do not have extensions for setting the 0th argument as the Bourne Again and Z shells have.  (The '93 Korn shell, and the MirBSD Korn shell from version R50e onwards, support an `-a` option to their built-in `exec` commands.)

## execline

[Laurent Bercot's `execline`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/index.html) comes with [an `exec` command](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/exec.html).  So to duplicate M. Chazelas' example one would have an `execline` script such as

```
#!/command/execlineb -P
exec -a zzz ps -f
```

Bercot's `exec` is an ordinary external command, of course.  So one could run it from within a Debian Almquist Shell script.  To overlay the current shell program one would use the shell's `exec` to overlay with Bercot `exec`, which in turn would set the 0th argument and overlay with the target program:

```
exec /command/exec -a "$argv0" printer.sh
```

## nosh

[The nosh toolset](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/) includes [an `exec` command](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/exec.xml).  To duplicate M. Chazelas' example one would have a `nosh` script such as

```
#!/bin/nosh
exec -a zzz ps -f
```

Although it is a `nosh` built-in, this `exec` is *also* accessible as an ordinary external command.  So one could run it from within a Debian Almquist Shell script.  To overlay the current shell program one would use the shell's `exec` to overlay with the nosh toolset's `exec`, which in turn would set the 0th argument and overlay with the target program:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/exec -a "$argv0" printer.sh
```

## perp

[Wayne Marshall's perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/) includes [a `runargv0` command](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runargv0.8).  This is an ordinary external command.  So one could run it from within a Debian Almquist Shell script.  To overlay the current shell program one would use the shell's `exec` to overlay with the perp toolset's `runargv0`, which in turn would set the 0th argument and overlay with the target program:

```
exec runargv0 printer.sh "$argv0"
```

## runit

[Gerrit Pape's runit](http://smarden.org/runit/index.html) includes [a `chpst` command](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html).  This is an ordinary external command.  So one could run it from within a Debian Almquist Shell script.  To overlay the current shell program one would use the shell's `exec` to overlay with runit's `chpst`, which in turn would set the 0th argument and overlay with the target program:

```
exec chpst -b "$argv0" printer.sh
```

## ucspi-tcp

[Daniel J. Bernstein's ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html) includes [an `argv0` command](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/argv0.html).  ([`argv0`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/argv0.xml) is also available in [djbwares](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/).) This is an ordinary external command.  So one could run it from within a Debian Almquist Shell script.  To overlay the current shell program one would use the shell's `exec` to overlay with ucspi-tcp's `argv0`, which in turn would set the 0th argument and overlay with the target program:

```
exec argv0 printer.sh "$argv0"
```

Comment: As a refugee from `runit` reluctantly turned to `systemd`, I'm very glad to be introduced to `nosh`. Many thanks!

Comment: With a `printer.sh` executable script which looks like `#! /bin/sh`, newline, `printf 'av0={%s}\n' "$0"`, will any of those programs be able to make it print something else than `av0={/path/to/printer.sh}`?

Comment: Fortunately, the question only asks how to set the argument, like the shells do, not how to cope with it being replaced by something else afterwards.  (-:  As both answers here say, there's a quite conformant way of doing that.  This answer points out that the C and C++ programs have already been written and compiled.  They've even been packaged for several operating systems in some cases.