# How can i run a program with modified argv[0] using busybox ash shell?

Tags: shell-script, busybox, exec, ash

In `bash` I would simply use `exec -a`. How can I do this in busybox? Is it even possible, or will I have to write my own C program to call `exec(3)` directly?

Comment: Where did you get the busybox binary, or how did you compile it? Does it use hush or ash (what's the output of `busybox sh --help`)?

Comment: It uses ash. lalala

Comment: @ali1234 Was your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

What version of busybox do you have? According to https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c if one delves around for `exec` one may encounter around line 9352 or so the following code which appears to support `exec [-a customname] ...`

```
execcmd(int argc UNUSED_PARAM, char **argv)
{
    optionarg = NULL;
    while (nextopt("a:") != '\0')
        /* nextopt() sets optionarg to "-a ARGV0" */;

    argv = argptr;
    if (argv[0]) {
        char *prog;

        iflag = 0;              /* exit on error */
        mflag = 0;
        optschanged();
        /* We should set up signals for "exec CMD"
         * the same way as for "CMD" without "exec".
         * But optschanged->setinteractive->setsignal
         * still thought we are a root shell. Therefore, for example,
         * SIGQUIT is still set to IGN. Fix it:
         */
        shlvl++;
        setsignal(SIGQUIT);
        /*setsignal(SIGTERM); - unnecessary because of iflag=0 */
        /*setsignal(SIGTSTP); - unnecessary because of mflag=0 */
        /*setsignal(SIGTTOU); - unnecessary because of mflag=0 */

        prog = argv[0];
        if (optionarg)
            argv[0] = optionarg;
        shellexec(prog, argv, pathval(), 0);
```

Comment: I have v1.25.1. This function is very different.

Comment: @ali1234 Then I think your busybox doesn't have this capability at all.

Answer (score 1):

[`exec -a` is supported since Busybox 1.27](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2017-July/085647.html), see also the answers to [Is there a POSIX way of setting zeroth argument of a target application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250681/is-there-a-posix-way-of-setting-zeroth-argument-of-a-target-application) for how to do achieve it some other way.