# How do I start a rxvt instance in a certain directory without using the "-cd" startup option (probably "quotes" wrong)?

Tags: bash, rxvt

I am playing around with the udiskie automount script. What I want is that after plugging in an external drive, a new rxvt terminal opens at the mount folder location.

Everything works, only problem is: if I launch the rxvt-terminal with the `-cd` option to change to the directory, it somehow prevents me from unmounting the drive, EVEN AFTER I cd to another directory. If I start the terminal without the `-cd` and cd to the mount directory manually, I can unmount as soon as I change to another directory; that's what I want. So my idea is to start rxvt with the `-hold` and the `-e` option to execute the `cd` somehow through that.

However, I cannot get that to work; rxvt always tells me "can't execute child" or something. In my script I tried everything like `rxvt-unicode -hold -e "/bin/bash -c cd $@"` (the script gets the mount path as an argument from udiskie, that works) with quotes in all combinations I could think of. Even `rxvt-unicode -hold -e "/bin/bash -c cd /etc"` fails, so I think something is messed up here.

Comment: Especially annoying is that if I start the terminal with the `-cd` option, I cannot unmount the drive until I close the terminal again, no matter from where and in which directory I am in the opened terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything works

On the contrary, neither of your approaches will work at all.  ☺

The `-cd` option to `urxvt` changes directory in the parent process, which becomes the terminal emulator on the master side of the pseudo-terminal, before forking the child.  The reason that you have problems unmounting is that the terminal emulator process retains that directory as its working directory.

(Note that this is not a problem exhibited by the client-server version of Unicode rvxt, `urxvtc`.)

There is no mode in which a conventional Unix shell executes a command from the `-c` option and then enters interactive mode reading from standard input.  This is not Microsoft's/IBM's `cmd` with its `/k` option.  ☺  You get *either* execution from standard input with no command *or* execution of a command with no execution from standard input; not both.

You unknowingly came close to the one approach that will work by trying to execute `cd` as though it were not a shell built-in.  (Your problem with not being able to execute the child is that the program name that you are trying to run is the single string `/bin/bash -c cd /etc` which is almost certainly not the name of a program image file on your system.)

In fact, there *are* standalone binaries whose sole actual job is to change working directory and then chain load to another program, which would be an interactive shell in this case.  The ones in my nosh toolkit and Laurent Bercot's execline toolkit are even named `chdir` and `cd`.  Wayne Marshall's tool is named `runtool`.

- ```
  urxvt -e chdir "$@" "$SHELL"
  ```
- ```
  urxvt -e cd "$@" "$SHELL"
  ```
- ```
  urxvt -e runtool -c "$@" "$SHELL"
  ```

The other remaining approach that will not quite give you what you want is to use the `ENV` environment variable.  Unfortunately, to make use of that, you need your interactive shell to be in POSIX-conformant mode, which is very likely not going to be the sort of interactive shell that you want; as well as a temporary script file, with all of the creation, security, and cleanup shenanighans that that entails.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [`chdir`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/chdir.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- [`cd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/cd.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *execline*.  skarnet.org.
- Wayne Marshall (2013). [`runtool`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runtool.8).  perp manual.  §8.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250708/5132

Comment: "There is no mode in which a conventional Unix shell executes a command from the -c option and then enters interactive mode reading from standard input. This is not Microsoft's/IBM's cmd with its /k option. ☺ You get either execution from standard input with no command or execution of a command with no execution from standard input; not both." - That is something I did not know; thanks for your really complete answer! Guess I'll have some more reading to do!

Comment: And really, it's actually just a minor inconvenience and probably not worth doing much more work....I just wanted to know where I was wrong!