# Is passing a different $0 to a child bash script possible?

Tags: bash, arguments

I know that this may sound as "not as intended by designer" but I have real life situation where a bash script I am modifying needs to call another bash script that I am not allowed to modify.

That "unmodifiable bash script" starts with:

```
source `dirname $0`/setenv.sh
```

(that `setenv.sh` also starts with `SCR2PATH=source "$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"` and is also unmodifiable)

Is there a trick in which I can fool the child script with a different `$0` than that of the calling script?

Comment: Is the unmodifiable child script sourced or called?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What value do you want `$0` to have? Can you show us the script you can actually modify? What is the `source "$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"` supposed to do? That will attempt to source a directory, you should be getting an error.

Comment: @icarus the unmodifiable child script is sourced. I can call it if if needed. Will this accomplish my objective, which is `dirname $0` returning the callee's directory instead of the caller's directory?

Comment: @terdon You are correct about "attempt to source a directory", I forgot to append yet another (unmodifiable) shell script to it. I want `$0` to have the unmodifieable script's directory rather then the modifiable script's directory.

Comment: @datsb so, you want one script you don't show us to source another script you don't show us which sources a third one which you also don't show us? I hope you can see how this is a little difficult to understand ;) Please edit your question and add the scripts. The best thing would be to make tiny, simple scripts that recreate the problem and show us those.

Comment: the `execve` system call allows setting $0 to any arbitrary value you just need a way to exploit fhat from inside your script.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250681/63149

Comment: @jasen that would not work for a bash script.  Bash needs to be invoked with a *correct* path for the script so it can load and interpret it.  It is bash, not the operating system that sets $0 for the script.

Comment: ah yes, execve  launches the interpreter in the shebang, that makes it harder to spoof $0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe this will do:

```
bash -c '. /path/to/unmodifiable' /fake/path args ...
```

Obviously, `/path/to/unmodifiable` should be a shell script; this silly trick won't work with other kind of executables. This also won't work with `zsh` (but will work with other shells like `dash`, `ksh`, etc).

If you have to *source* instead of *call* the unmodifiable script, you can use the same trick from a wrapper calling your outer script, or have it re-call itself:

```
$ cat unmodifiable
#! /bin/sh
printf '{%s} ' "$0" "$@"
echo

$ cat becoming
#! /bin/sh
[ "$MYSELF" ] || MYSELF=$0 exec sh -c '. "$MYSELF"' "I'm the mountain!" "$@"
. ./unmodifiable

$ chmod 755 becoming
$ ./becoming 1 2 3
{I'm the mountain!} {1} {2} {3}
```

Comment: Your `bash -c '. /path/to/unmodifiable' /fake/path args ...` trick works like a charm.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot "fool" the child script, but you can call it via a different name by creating a symlink to the called script and calling the symlink. This will, I believe achieve the objective you are looking for.

Example:

```
$ cat ./bin/script.sh
echo $0

$ ./bin/script.sh
./bin/script.sh
$ ln -s bin/script.sh foo.sh
$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh
```

Comment: I may have described my objective unclearly: `foo.sh` is in the directory that I need to be returned by `dirname`. script.sh (which calls `foo.sh`) is in a different directory. When script.sh calls `foo.sh` (using `source`),  the `dirname $0` in foo.sh reports script.sh's directory, not foo.sh's -- which is exactly the opposite of what's needed.

Comment: so symlink it into the directory you want... assuming that directory is writable by you.  If it is not, then I think you're out of luck :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exec -a` in a subshell: `(exec -a fakeDollarZero /unmodifiable/bash/script the rest of the args)`

Unlike [mosvy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558960/217726), this would work even if it were something other than a bash script.

Comment: this does not work with executable scripts (no matter the language they're written in), but only with binaries.