# Changing argv[0] from the command line

Tags: shell, arguments

I remember many years (decades) ago using a system where one could say something like:

```
$ realname:newname A B C
```

and the program would be invoked with `argv = { "newname", "A", "B", "C" }`.

I don't remember what shell this was though.

Does such a capability exist in any current shells?

UPDATE:

`exec -a` looked like it was what I wanted, but I'm getting inconsistent behaviour depending upon the program's language (yes, I know it's awful code):

```
$ cat argv.c  && cc argv.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("<< %s >>\n", argv[0]); }

$ (exec -a fake ./a.out)
<< fake >>
```

It works fine in "C", but not in python:

```
$ cat argv.py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
print("<<", sys.argv[0], ">>")

$ (exec -a fake ./argv.py)
<< /home/ray/test/argv.py >>
```

Comment: just to be clear, though it's already said in some answers but your python version works as expected. you want `sys.argv[1]` instead

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh` (since the first release in 1990):

```
$ ARGV0="new value for ps's argv[0]" ps -f
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
stephane   45193    2195  0 12:08 pts/11   00:00:00 /bin/zsh
stephane   45510   45193  0 12:15 pts/11   00:00:00 new value for ps's argv[0] -f
```

`zsh` also has a `-` builtin to start a command with `-` prepended to `argv[0]` (as used to start shells as login shells):

```
$ - ps -f
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
stephane    2221    2195  0 06:21 pts/4    00:00:01 /bin/zsh
stephane   46537    2221  0 12:42 pts/4    00:00:00 -ps -f
```

ksh (since 1993), bash (since 2.0 in 1996), [zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2007/msg00289.html) (since 4.3.5 in 2008), bosh (since the 2015-08-27 release), mksh (since R52c in 2016), busybox `ash` (since 1.27.0 (2017)) at least:

```
$ (exec -a "new value for ps's argv[0]" ps -f)
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
stephane    2221    2195  0 06:21 pts/4    00:00:01 /bin/zsh
stephane   46558    2221  0 12:43 pts/4    00:00:00 new value for ps's argv[0] -f
```

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -e 'exec {shift} @ARGV' /bin/ps "new value for ps's argv[0]" -f
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
stephane   46585    2195  0 12:44 pts/14   00:00:00 /bin/zsh
stephane   46646   46585  0 12:45 pts/14   00:00:00 new value for ps's argv[0] -f
```

With `python`:

```
$ python3 -c 'import os; import sys; os.execvp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])' ps "new value for ps's argv[0]" -f 
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
stephane   46585    2195  0 12:44 pts/14   00:00:00 /bin/zsh
stephane   46985   46585  0 12:53 pts/14   00:00:00 new value for ps's argv[0] -f
```

But beware that when you execute a script (with the `execve()` system call) that starts with:

```
#! /path/to/interpreter optional-arg
```

as shebang as:

```
execve("/path/to/script", ["arg0", "arg1", ...], env)
```

The system transforms it to:

```
execve("/path/to/interpreter", [something, "optional-arg", "/path/to/script", "arg1", ...], env)
```

With `something` being, [depending on the system](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/shebang/) either `/path/to/interpreter` or `argv0` (the former on Linux).

And interpreters, when exposing arg lists in their API, expose the argument list *of the script*, not *of the interpreter*, so `$0` / `sys.argv[0]` will not be `something` above, but `/path/to/script`.

Comment: What a great, comprehensive answer on just about everything relevant.

Answer (score 3):

When starting a shell using its `-c` option to run an in-line script, the first argument will be placed in `$0`:

```
$ sh -c 'printf "0: %s\n" "$0"; printf "Other: %s\n" "$@"'  hello there how are you
0: hello
Other: there
Other: how
Other: are
Other: you
```

In `bash`, assigning to `BASH_ARGV0` changes the current shell's `$0` value:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$0"
/usr/local/bin/bash
$ BASH_ARGV0="hello"
$ printf '%s\n' "$0"
hello
```

(but it does not change the process' name on my system)

Using `set`, you'd change the other arguments:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"

$ set -- A B C
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

A symlink maybe enought for most systems:

```
~$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    printf("%s\n", av[0]);
}
~$ cc -o test test.c
~$ ./test 
./test
~$ ln -s test coincoin 
~$ ./coincoin 
./coincoin
```

This is the mechanism used by `busybox` (widely used in embedded systems) to implement several utilities (ping, route, etc...) using only one binary.

Comment: Also common on many systems to do similar things. On OpenBSD, for example, the `cksum`, `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256` and `sha512` utilities are all the same file with different names (hard links).

Answer (score 0):

[not a real answer yet]

When used with a she-banged executable script, neither

```
execl("/path/to/script", "new_av0", (void*)0)
```

in C, nor

```
exec -a new_av0 /path/to/script
```

in shells which support `exec -a` will be able to set `$0` or `sys.argv[0]` (or whatever language syntax is used to refer to the zeroth argument) in that script.

When executing the interpreter of a she-banged script, the kernel will irretrievably discard the original zeroth argument, splicing in its place the name of the interpreter, any optional she-bang line argument, and the path to the script.

Any solution is bound to be tricky, limited or language/system dependent.

For instance, a shell script could be [fooled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558960/308316) with:

```
sh -c '. /path/to/script' new_av0
```

But obviously, this will not affect the command line as it appears in the output of `ps`, `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, `/proc/<pid>/comm` etc.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I see that FreeBSD ports has the `argv0` command since around version 7.1 (2009)