# What's an example usage of the zsh precommand modifier -?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I came across this precommand modifier in `man zshbuiltins` which refers to `man zshmisc`.
I tried searching for examples, but didn't find any.

Here's what my `man zshmisc` page shows:

```
PRECOMMAND MODIFIERS
   A simple command may be preceded by a precommand modifier, which  will  alter
   how  the  command is interpreted.  These modifiers are shell builtin commands
   with the exception of nocorrect which is a reserved word.

   -      The command is executed with a `-' prepended to its argv[0] string.
```

Here's what I tried:

```
prompt> - echo
cd: no such file or directory: /Users/bmiller286/Projects/bgovecholonestar-eventsvc
```

What's an example or two of how to use this precommand modifier?

EDIT:
It looks like `oh-my-zsh` aliased `-` to be `cd -`, which explains why `cd` was complaining.
So far, I've only seen one use case that supports this paradigm of prepending an `-` to `argv[0]`--and that's login shells.

The documentation (above) acts like this is a common paradigm not specific to login shells.
So,

1. Is this basically a login-shell only thing?
2. If not, is this a common easter egg that many programs support?
3. If I were wanting to do an internet search for programs that support it, what would I search for? (it's hard to search for `-` because many engines see it as a negative operator. Even searching for precommand modifiers turned up pretty much nothing for this thing)

Comment: See also: [Changing argv\[0\] from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666850)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for that reference.  I tried running each of those examples (terminal commands) and none of them worked for me. When I tried executing `- ps -f` I received `cd: too many arguments`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Also, when I ran `ARGV0="new value for ps's argv[0]" ps -f`, I didn't see `new value for ps's argv[0]` anywhere in the list.

Comment: You might have an alias that overrides the `-` builtin. See what `type -- -` outputs

Comment: Are you even sure you're running the `zsh` shell. What's the output of `echo "$ZSH_VERSION"; emulate`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wow, you're right!  I'm using oh-my-zsh.  I wonder if that added it.  I'll go see how to unalias it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm running version `5.7.1` as per the output of your command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas when I run `unalias -` I get `unalias: not enough arguments`.  I'm pretty sure I didn't have that problem with other aliases in the past.  Do I have to do something special to unalias `-`?

Comment: `-` is the end-of-option marker in zsh builtins like in the Bourne / Korn shells, and like `--` in POSIX utilities. So, you'd need `unalias - -` or `unalias -- -` (both `-` and `--` are supported as end-of-option marker in `zsh`, like in modern versions of ksh).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. I also found a way: `unalias -m '\-'`.  Now `- ps -f` runs without error, but doesn't display like it does on that first link.  Maybe it's working and I can't connect the dots.

Comment: What does `- ps -f` show? How about `- ps -o args`? What's your OS? Is it Unix-like? Do you possibly also have a `ps` function overriding the `ps` command? What does `type ps` give you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129733/discussion-between-brandon-and-stephane-chazelas).

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
% cat > .bash_login
echo this is a login shell
% bash
bash$ exit
% - bash
this is a login shell
bash$
```

or in English: Some shells check their `argv[0]`, and if there's a leading dash there, they go into "login shell" mode. Whatever that means for the various shells, probably changes to which startup files are read, at least. For Bash, see [6.1 Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) and [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html); for zsh, at least [5.1 Startup/Shutdown Files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) in the manual mentions login shells (but I can't find the part where it says how the shell determines if it's a login shell).

I suppose Zsh just gives a simple way to access that functionality, here, in case you'd need it. There might be other ways to do that too, at least Bash and Dash take the `-l` option to mean the same thing.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a good search string that I may use to find more information about this behavior?

Comment: @Brandon, "login shell"?

Comment: It does look like `- zsh` will open zsh in login shell mode.  It looks like a handful of other programs also use the leading dash in ARGV[0] to signal it to do something special.  This whole thing is new to me and I am finding it difficult to get my mind wrapped around this easter-egg-of-sorts behavior.  Is there an abstract way to look at the -<program> argv[0] paradigm?  Perhaps a common feature name?  Or is this one of those *nix things that got started back in 1970ish that is still supported but we can mostly forget about?

Comment: @Brandon you keep sayin "Easter egg" as if this is some hidden joke from the devs. On the contrary, this is a well-known, widely prevalent way of starting login shells. Even fish with its upending of conventions [conforms to this](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/b2f791b577e9041fbe28042771b80146849d37af/src/fish.cpp#L398). Of course *you* can forget about it, it's not as if you're writing a shell that you hope will become widely used, are you?

Comment: @Brandon, well, it's a documented feature, so not really an Easter Egg, though I can see it might look like that. I don't know the real history here, but it might be something that "seemed a good idea at the time", and then got stuck. Like the thing about having `ls` hide all files that start with a dot, and not just `.` and `..`. Some programs do change their behaviour based on the name they're started with, e.g. Busybox (determines which utility to run), and zsh (compatibility modes). Maybe `grep`/`egrep` on some systems, too. But AFAIK the `-` thing is specific to login shells.